# Can someone explain why the below Kotlin code produces incorrect expected result?

Tags: kotlin

Can someone explain why the below code produces `[2,3,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]`?
I know it has something to do with filter function is deferred to the last element but I don't see the picture.  It would even be better if you can visualise it.  Thank you so much.

```
val primes: Sequence<Int> = sequence {
    var numbers = generateSequence(2) { it + 1 }

    var prime: Int
    while (true) {
        prime = numbers.first()
        yield(prime)
        numbers = numbers.drop(1).filter { it % prime != 0 }
    }
}
print(primes.take(10).toList())
```

Answer (score -1):

it's because you change `prime` variable in `filter` closure. For example, on the second step you have `numbers` as `.filter { it % prime != 0 }.filter { it % prime != 0 }` but the `prime` is one variable, and it is equal to `3`

Correct version:

```kotlin
val primes: Sequence<Int> = sequence {
    var numbers = generateSequence(2) { it + 1 }

    while (true) {
        val prime = numbers.first()
        yield(prime)
        numbers = numbers.drop(1).filter { it % prime != 0 }
    }
}
print(primes.take(10).toList())
```

Comment: Then why 4 get filtered out?

Comment: after the second step (which returned `3`) your `numbers` variable is something like `generateSequence(2) { it + 1 }.drop(1).filter { it % 3 != 0 }.drop(1).filter { it % 3 != 0 }` so `3` will be filtered out by `filter` when `2` and `4` will be dropped with two `drop(1)`